# Question regarding proof that a finite morphism is proper.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that a morphism $f: X \to Y$ is proper if and only if $Y$ can be covered by open subsets $V_i$ such that $f^{-1}(V_i) \to V_i$ is proper for each $i$.

If a morphism is finite we can cover $Y$ by open affines $V_i$ such that $f^{-1}(V_i)$ can be covered by open affines $U_{ij}$. The proof I am reading makes the statement that since $f$ is affine we can immediately assume that both $Y$ and $X$ are affine. It makes complete sense that we can assume this for $Y$. However, I don't see how we are allowed to make this assumption for $X$.

We only know that the preimage of an affine in $Y$ can be covered by affines, but this does not imply that the preimage is affine itself.

Why can I assume that $X$ is an affine scheme given that $f$ is a finite morphism?

Comment: What is your definition of a finite morphism? Part of mine is that the morphism is _affine_; that is, the inverse image of an affine open is affine. (In general you can always cover any open set by affines, so your condition doesn't seem to say much.)

Comment: Ok. I have not seen the definition of affine morphism yet. It doesn't come up until later in the book it seems. (on pg. 128)

Comment: Er, sorry, of "finite". He includes this assumption. The notion of "affine" is treated in the exercises.

Comment: Oh ok. My bad. I was thinking of finite type :( Bad question is retrospect but ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are still looking for an answer, you also need that finite maps are closed maps and that they are stable under base extension, this proves that they are universally closed. By definition, finite maps are also separated and clearly of finite type. So it is proper.